# How may I split my JavaScript classes across multiple files and yet have them belong to the same namespace?

Tags: javascript

I learnt that you could mimic namespaces in JavaScript by scoping your classes / objects inside a function expression or an object literal. That way the containing object or function provides a namespace and scope for the contained.

But for those to work, all the contained objects have to be within the same file, right?

Because if I had two namespace / naming container objects with the same name in two different files, they would overwrite each other depending on the order in which I included the source files.

**File1.js**

```
var Automtomobiles = 
{
  function Wheel() { ... }
};
```

**File2.js**

```
var Automtomobiles = 
{
  function Car() { ... }
};
```

How do I span objects / class definitions across multiple files but keep them within a same namespace?

Comment: By making namespace global

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make Automtomobiles as global object

File1.js

```
var Automtomobiles = Automtomobiles || {};
Automtomobiles.wheel = function() {
}
```

File2.js

```
var Automtomobiles = Automtomobiles || {};
Automtomobiles.car = function() {
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What's that `||` and where may I read about it? Does it append all other declarations of the `Automobiles` namespace / object from all the other files and merge them into a single declaration?

Comment: I used || operator beacuse, no matter In what order you load your files, all should work. So if file2 is loaded first then Automobiles will be {}. and car property will be attached to it. And when file1 loads, the Automobiles will be an object with car property. If you know the first file which be loaded you can simply declare var Automobiles = {}; in that file only. Then you don't need to use || operator

Comment: @Water Cooler v2, `||` is OR operator.

Comment: Thank you both. I am aware of the `||` operator for its use in the evaluation of logical expressions. However, this usage is not implied. In other words, this has got to be something built into JavaScript (and fairly documented) as you cannot do this with any language that has the logical OR operator. Where may I read about this usage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript

Comment: @mike510a I read that question before asking this one. I can't see where there's an explanation of this particular usage of the `||` operator in that question.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, I don't think there is special documentation for what you want. As It is very simple as  I have already mentioned in previous comment

Comment: The statement basically performs this:     var Automtobiles is equal to whatever value it had before OR if it has not been previous defined,then it is equal to an empty object identified by  `{ }` Anytime you put a logical operation on to the right side of a definition  like  `var something = (logical operation)`  then that operation is carried out and the result is used to determine the next action (in this case the logical operation was ||   and any object can be tested for existence by simply testing if a defiition is non-zero

Comment: @mike510a I know and can infer very easily what it does. I wanted to read about it from the documentation.

Comment: https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/27/javascript-namespaces-and-modules/    third or fourth topic

Answer (score 1):

To make them global you can use  `window.Automtobiles = function()` or to define an static property to a `type`. You can use `.prototype`

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}
Person.prototype.nationality = "English";

console.log(new Person("john", "smith", 20, "red"));
```

Note how "English" is attached to each instance of `Person` after using the Prototype function

For your particular case, you can define `Automtobiles` then prototype it..

```js
function Automtomobiles() {

};

Automtomobiles.prototype.wheel = function() { ... }
Automtomobiles.prototype.car = function() { ... }
```

Comment: I know about prototypal inheritance. My question is about splitting objects across multiple source files under a same context / namespace / naming container.

Comment: as long as their within the same `document`  (web page)  they will all be within the global namespace or whatever namespace you specify

Comment: Oh yes, essentially the same as @Kenny's suggestion. Nice hack. So, I infer that there's no way other than to make the code a bit convoluted by either adding to an existing class' prototype or to an existing object. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript you could use the common notation that lot of libraries use. For one file:

```
var Automtomobiles;
(function (Automtomobiles) {
    var Wheel = (function () {
        function Wheel() {};        
        return Wheel;
    }());
    Automtomobiles.Wheel = Wheel;
})(Automtomobiles || (Automtomobiles = {}));
```

And the other file:

```
var Automtomobiles;
(function (Automtomobiles) {
    var Car= (function () {
        function Car() {};      
        return Car;
    }());
    Automtomobiles.Car= Car;
})(Automtomobiles || (Automtomobiles = {}));
```

Anyway, if you are open to use third party libraries, they could help you too. Long time ago I used [Dojo declare](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/declare/) feature, which manages the namespaces and class names for you, althoug I'm sure that at current exists more libraries to reach that.

In fact, you also could use `Typescript`, which is perfect to reach your goal and vey use to learn. The code generated by `Typescript` looks like the examples I posted above.